# "The old jive broad split" meaning - Bill Withers Song (Ain't no Sunshine)

Tags: american-english, slang, lyrics

> "The old jive broad split"

It's a part of what Bill Withers says at the beginning of "Ain't no sunshine".

It's a part of the story behind this song. But it lacks everything. I have absolutely no idea about its meaning or even its gramatical structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found Bill Withers' intro to the song [**here**.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-hvb1rGSE8) His full statement is:

> Women can say stuff like, "I loved him, I really really loved him. But he just left. Why'd he leave like that?"
>   Men, given the same situation, usually say somethin' like, **"I'm glad the old jive broad split, man,"** knowing all the time that it's really killin' him inside.

Here's the breakdown of the slang words used:

> [**old**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/old) = *(informal - adj)* "Used to express affection, familiarity, or **contempt**."
>
> [**jive**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jive) = *(North American - informal - adj)* "Deceitful or **worthless**."
>
> [**broad**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/broad) = *(North American - informal - noun)* "A **woman**."
>
> [**split**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/split) = *(informal - no object)* "**Leave** a place, especially suddenly."

So he is giving an example of how a man usually hides his feelings after a woman leaves him. That line means:

> "I'm glad that old jive broad split" = (disrespectfully) I am glad that worthless woman left me

He finishes explaining that he didn't want to be like that, so he wrote the lyrics, *"Ain't no sunshine when she's gone,"* to speak honestly instead.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is parsed as follows:

> (The ((old, jive) broad) split)

In other words, the "broad" - who is "old" and "jive" - "split". All of these are used in a slang / colloquial sense:

---

> **[jive](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jive)** *adj. Slang*
>   ...
>   Misleading, phony, or worthless: *talking jive nonsense.*

---

> **[old](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/old)** *adj.*
>   ...
>   Used as an intensive: *Come back any old time. Don't give me any ol' excuse.*

---

> **[broad](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/broad)** *n. Offensive Slang*
>   ...
>   A woman or girl.

---

> **[split](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/split)** *v. Slang* ... To depart from; leave: *a mobster who suddenly split town.*

---

So the meaning of the lyrics are that a woman left, or broke up with, the narrator, and the narrator is referring to the woman in derogatory way out of frustration, regret, a broken heart, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The full context is ***I'm glad the old jive broad split***. From [the full OED...](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101381?rskey=DFSA0E&result=2#eid)

> **jive** U.S. slang
>     Used, chiefly by black Americans, in the primary sense ‘not acting correctly’ but with a wide range of connotations (‘pretentious’, ‘deceitful’, etc.).

In the cited context, ***broad*** is an old-time (disrespectful) slang term for a ***woman***, and ***split*** is slang for ***left, went away***.

The speaker is glad some particular woman left him (he didn't think highly of her anyway).